# How do I create a null value (skip a cell) when entering a literal array in Google Sheets?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, formulas, array-formulas

I would like to create a master template that only contains one formula by using the following in B2:

```
=arrayformula({left(A2:A),right(A2:A)})
```

Where the user only enters data in column A.

Suppose I would like the user to enter data in column A, perform calculations in columns B and C, have the user enter other data in column D, and then perform one more calculation in column E.

How do I write a literal array to skip column D, so that the user can enter data there without causing: "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in D2"?  The following is my futile attempt at skipping column D:

```
=arrayformula({left(A2:A),right(A2:A),,mid(D2:D,2,1)})
```

This obviously yields a formula parse error.

Comment: even if you succeed in creating an empty column with a formula, it won't work: Any attempt at writing in this column (manually) will destroy the formula.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I write a literal array to skip column D, so that the user can enter data there without causing: "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in D2"?

Instead of using a single formula, use two formulas, one to fill columns B and C and another to fill column E.

Using a single formula will cause the error that you described.

Comment: I appreciate the response and I do recognize this as a solution.  However, my goal was to make "ultimate" templates that only have one formula on the whole sheet.  Perhaps, this goal is too lofty.